# RxJS operator for left joining 2 observables

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to left join 2 Observables such that I always take the value from ObservableA, unless there is a corresponding value from ObservableB. In which case I want to use the value from ObservableB. The two Observables should join so will be a akin to a SQL left join.

From reading the RxJS Operators tree it does seem to me that [Join](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#Join) would be the logical choice. I am unclear on how the join window works and how to ensure either observable could result in a join happening.

Can anyone provide a *simple* example?

Comment: What you mean by 'a corresponding value from ObservableB"?

Comment: I mean I want to join the 2. e.g. if both observables had id properties, when they match I would want B's value in the resulting observable. Otherwise, if no match, I'd want the value from A.

Comment: If obsA emits first, does it have to wait for a value from obsB? or after each observable emit once, obsA emits 3 new values, does it have to take the latest value from obsB?

Comment: This question is heavily under-specified. Observables are data *over time*, so you need to be clear on how you want to handle this aspect in your case.

Comment: Fair point. I would like to join whenever a new item is added to either observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with just `merge` where you put ObservableB first and then use `take(1)` to complete immediately. If ObservableB was empty then it'll emit the value from ObservableA.

```
const a$ = of(1);
const b$ = of('a');

merge(b$, a$)
  .pipe(
    take(1),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-u5syjx?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no out of the box operator for this. But you may want to `zip` first, then `map` the results with your custom logic to get what you want:

```
zip(observableA, observableB).map([a,b] =>{
if(idMatchesWithB) {return b}
else {return a}
}
```

Comment: If the observable aren’t of the same length & order would Zip be the wrong choice? That was my understanding.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you use zip and one observable is lengthy, then the extra values from that observable will be ignored. Or you might want to use combineLatest, ii is up to you. You may check the docs for zip and combineLatest: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#categories-of-operators